# How to access the asp.net dropdownlist selected item value from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, drop-down-menu

How to access the asp.net dropdownlist selecteditem value from javascript?
I have the following code here where i want to access the dropdownlist selecteditem value in the javascript , and pass that value as a query string to another page

```
      function Example()
                 {

                     var e =  $find("ExampleDropDownList");
                     var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
                     alert(strUser);
                     window.radopen("ExampleDetail.aspx?Id=" + strUser, "Dailog");
                     return false;
                }

 <telerik:RadComboBox ID="ExampleDropDownList" runat="server" >
    </telerik:RadComboBox>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.Net Controls always render back into plain HTML Controls.
When using javascript you can call the item exactly as you normaly would a dropdown. The dropdown list will have the ID of your RadComboBox.

var myDropDown = document.getElementById('ExampleDropDownList');

and you will have access to your dropdown list.

Comment: how to access the selected item value?

Comment: var myDropDownSelectedValue = myDropDown.options[myDropDown.selectedIndex].value;